# How to show different pages depending on URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am studying to make my own homepage using Javascript and nodejs.

I practiced diverse examples that has only one page.

But, I wonder how I connect each pages inside a homepage?

For example,

https://stackoverflow.com/

this is url of main page of stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

And when I click ask , the page is changed with diferent url.

I 've not searched this kind of example on google or youtube.

Could you recommed some tutorial on google or youtube to learn these?

And How to say this kind of example?

Thank you so much.

Comment: React router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: @SakoBu There is no React mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SlawomirWozniak - oops :) I had filtered the questions to show react related but somehow...  my mistake...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is called "Routing", and you can do it either on client, or server side.

Basically you create a big `switch` statement, or a few `if's` in your server.

```
const url = require('url');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
   const path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
   // If or switch
   if (path === '/'){
     res.send(stuff);
   } else {
     res.send(otherStuff);
   }
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).